# Integral question $\int\,{ x^3 e^{x^2}\over (x^2 +1)^2}\,\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integral question
 $$\int\,{ x^3 e^{x^2}\over (x^2 +1)^2}\,\text{d}x$$

I'm stock in this question.I try to 
substitute something. But it's not effective.

Is anyone know how to do or which method should I try?

Comment: What might ${\text{e}^x}^2$ mean?  Does it mean $(\text{e}^x)^2$ or $\text{e}^{(x^2)}$?

Comment: But should you mean to say $\int\,\frac{x^3\exp\left(x^2\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\,\text{d}x$, the integral can be simplified by letting $y:=x^2$.  Plus, $$\frac{y\,\exp(y)}{(y+1)^2}=\frac{(y+1)\,\exp(y)-\exp(y)\cdot 1}{(y+1)^2}$$ should remind you of something of the form $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)=\frac{v\,u'-u\,v'}{v^2}\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski Yes,it is. Sorry I don't type it well.

Comment: "Yes, it is" is a nonsensical response to an "Is it [A] or [B]?" kind of questions.  A proper response should be "it is [A]" or "it is [B]" in this situation.

Comment: @Batominovski sorry,it is  $e^{x^2}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int \frac x {(x^{2}+1)^{2}} (x^{2}e^{x^{2}})dx=-\frac 1 {2(1+x^{2})}(x^{2}e^{x^{2}})+\int \frac 1 {2(1+x^{2})} e^{x^{2}} (2x+2x^{3})dx=-\frac 1 {2(1+x^{2})}(x^{2}e^{x^{2}})+\int xe^{x^{2}}dx=-\frac 1 {2(1+x^{2})}(x^{2}e^{x^{2}})+\frac 1 2 e^{x^{2}}+c $

Comment: Thank you i got it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $x^2+1=y\implies2x\ dx=dy$

$$2eI=\int\dfrac{e^y(y-1)}{y^2}dy=e^y\left(\dfrac1y+\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac1y\right)}{dy}\right)=\dfrac{e^y}y+K$$

as $\dfrac{d(e^yf(y))}{dy}=?$